# How to correctly use the querybuilder in order to do a subselect?

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I would like to do a subselect in order to do the following postgresql query with the querybuilder:

```
SELECT i.* FROM internship i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT iw.* 
              FROM internship_weeks iw
              WHERE i.id = iw.internship)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get the same result with queryBuilder? or maybe with DQL?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As example, only for demonstrate HOW-TO use a subquery select statement inside a select statement, suppose we what to find all user that not yet have compile the address (no records exists in the address table):

```
 // get an ExpressionBuilder instance, so that you
$expr = $this->_em->getExpressionBuilder();

// create a subquery
$sub = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('iw')
    ->from(IntershipWeek::class, 'iw')
    ->where('i.id = iw.intership');


$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('i')
    ->from(Intership::class, 'u')
    ->where($expr->exists($sub->getDQL()));

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Hope this help